Are Publish immediate DML and DML Statements 2 different limit sets in Apex transaction?
We see in a debug log, as below:
Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
Number of publish immediate DML: 59 out of 150

Do we have separate limits for above 2 for a single transaction in apex?

Tried out with below code snippet
If platform event behaviour is set to Publish After Commit, received Too many DML statements: 151 exception which means total 150 DML operations are allowed and no separate limits available even though it is listed separately in debug logs.
If platform event behaviour is set to Publish Immediately, did not receive Too many DML statements: 151 exception which means separate limits are available.
Code snippet used for testing:
Account accountObject; 
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    accountobject = new Account();
    accountobject.Name = 'Test ' + i;
    insert accountObject;
}

Test_Platform__e testEvent = new Test_Platform__e();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    testEvent = new Test_Platform__e();
    EventBus.publish (testEvent);
}


Was your platform event configured to publish immediately?

I copy-pasted this into my org, but with a different platform event, and it ran successfully. The error you got indicates that the platform event you used for testing was not set to Publish Immediately, so it counted against the normal DML limits.

Thanks. Tried with both settings for clarity.

Yes, we do. In the documentation, it says:



Description
Synchronous Limit
Asynchronous Limit




...
...
...


Total number of DML statements issued2
150
150


...
...
...


Maximum number of EventBus.publish calls for platform events configured to publish immediately
150
150



